# How to generate unique node names from nodeset?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have this legacy nodeset which is essentially a shipping schedule:

```
<destinations>
    <voyage>
        <entry>
            <port>
                <item>Zeebrügge</item>
            </port>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <port>
                <item>Bremerhaven</item>
            </port>
        </entry>
    </voyage>
    <voyage>
        <entry>
            <port>
                <item>Bremerhaven</item>
            </port>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <port>
                <item>Zeebrügge</item>
            </port>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <port>
                <item>Vigo</item>
            </port>
        </entry>
    </voyage>
    <voyage>
        <entry>
            <port>
                <item>Zeebrügge</item>
            </port>
        </entry>
    </voyage>
    <voyage>
        <entry>
            <port>
                <item>Bremerhaven</item>
            </port>
        </entry>
    </voyage>
</destinations>
```

Is there a way to generate a list of the **unique** `ports` from that nodeset?

So the result would be something like this:

```
<result>
   <item>Zeebrügge</item>
   <item>Bremerhaven</item>
   <item>Vigo</item>
</result>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a technique called [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) to do this in XSLT 1.0 (as that involves getting the first element for each distinct value to get the "groups").

Start off by defining a key like so:

```
<xsl:key name="items" match="item" use="." />
```

And to get the distinct items, do this....

```
<xsl:copy-of select="//item[generate-id() = generate-id(key('items', .)[1])]" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:key name="items" match="item" use="." />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <result>
      <xsl:copy-of select="//item[generate-id() = generate-id(key('items', .)[1])]" />
    </result>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use do this too if using XSLT 2.0

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="2.0">
<xsl:output indent="yes"></xsl:output>
<xsl:template match="destinations">
    <result>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="//item" group-by="distinct-values(.)">
        <xsl:copy><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:copy>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
    </result>
</xsl:template>
```